# Is a negative covid test result required for transit at Malaysia?

Tags: transit, covid-19, malaysia

I'm travelling from NZ to Dubai via Malaysia, 6h stopover at Kuala Lumpur International Airport. I'm fully vaccinated and boosted (3 Pfizer doses). Does anyone know if it is necessary to take a PCR test just to transit at Malaysia? Dubai doesn't require any testing to enter their country.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because covid restrictions are now over.